# A control with ID could not be found - One Update Panel has trigger, another UpdatePanel needs to be updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an 2 Update Panel Namely (IDs) as upDMList for UpdatePanel 1 and UpdatePanel2 for second UpdatePanel. I have a Gridview inside UpdatePanel1 which has LinkButton. This Link button need to act as Trigger for second Update Panel but it always shows error

I have tried various methods
**For Example -  When I target Control using Gridview ID it shows this error**
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A control with ID 'gvDMList$lnkAccountImage' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel2'.

**When I Target Control Using only Link Button ID it shows Error**
A control with ID 'lnkAccountImage' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel2'.

**Even while targetting using Update Panel 1 ID the error is**
A control with ID 'upDMList$gvDMList$lnkAccountImage' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel2'.

Both UpdatePanel has ChildrenAsTriggers set to true and ClientIDMode=Static
Any help would be useful

Here is relevant code

```
`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDMList" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvDMList" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="false" style="margin: 0 auto" DataKeyNames="DMID" OnRowCreated="gvDMList_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="gvDMList_RowDataBound" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvDMList_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="gvDMList_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvDMList_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDMList_PageIndexChanging" CssClass="table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed" runat="server">
                                <Columns>                          <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="GetImage" ClientIDMode="Static" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("FileName") %>' ID="lnkAccountImage" OnClick="lnkAccountImage_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" Text="Show Image"></asp:LinkButton></td>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass ="btn btn-default" CausesValidation="false" ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true"/>

                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>`
```

**Second Update Panel**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgAcnt" CssClass="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block" AlternateText="Account Details Image" runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkAccountImage" EventName="Click" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I am just guessing but can you add property in updatepanel2 for UpdateMode = "Always" and remove trigger code from link button.

Comment: I Should change UpdateMode="Always" for UpdatePanel1 which has girdview and link button or second Updatepanel which need to Updated after link button click?

Comment: second one to update

Comment: Done. Still same error

Comment: have you removed code for updating updatepanel2 ??

Comment: There never was any code for that

I'll edit the first post to show code

Comment: and also code for lnkAccountImage_Click

Comment: Well I removed the Trigger altogether and updated 2nd Updatepanel in code behind. This solved the problem for me.